# Solving simultaneous equations with 3 parts

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, systems-of-equations

I keep trying to solve this problem, but i keep on getting crazy answers, i think i am right up to a certain point and then doing something wrong, the question is to solvie this :

$$
\begin{align*}
    2x^2 + 3y + z &= 8\\
    x - 2y &= 4\\
    3z - x &= 7  
\end{align*}
$$

I've tried many things but can't work out what i'm doing wrong, any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use $x-2y=4$ to get $\frac{1}{2}x-2=y$.  You can use $3z-x=7$ to get $z=\frac{7}{3}+\frac{1}{3}x$.  Plug these into $2x^2+3y+z=8$ to get

$$
2x^2+3\left(\frac{1}{2}x-2\right) +\frac{7}{3}+\frac{1}{3}x=8.
$$

Simplify and use quadratic formula to find values of $x$.  Then use the above equations to get $z$ and $y$.

Comment: awesome that worked, i was doing it where i multiplied the top so the other 2 fitted nice, and i must of done that wrong, so i kept getting the wrong answer, Thanks for your help!